# How to retrieve the most recent Active Record objects per column combination?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model called `Event` which belongs to `Area` and `Task`. I'm attempting to retrieve a collection of events that only contains the most recent event per area and task combination. That is, I only want the most recent event of the events that have the same area_id and task_id. Example collection of events:

```
|event_id|area_id|task_id| ... |
|--------|-------|-------|-----|
|      5 |     3 |     2 | ... |
|      4 |     3 |     1 | ... |
|      3 |     3 |     2 | ... |
```

Here I want only event 5 and 4 to be returned since 3 is older.

I've tried using `Event.select(:area_id,:task_id).distinct` which seems to work, but strips all other attributes of the returned events, including `:id`. Grateful for any help or suggestions!

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: MySQL 5.6.27 (on AWS RDS)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use raw SQL inside `select`, so you could try something like this:

```
Event.select("DISTINCT(CONCAT(area_id, task_id)), id, attr1, attr2")
```

Where `id`, `attr1` and `attr2` are the other attributes from your `Event` table.

Or you could use `.group` instead of `.distinct` and forget about using raw SQL:

```
Event.all.group(:area_id,:task_id)
```

You will get the same result as using `DISTINCT` and all attributes will be available.

**UPDATE**

To order before grouping, you can use `find_by_sql` with nested queries (again, raw SQL):

```
Event.find_by_sql(
  "SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM `events`
    ORDER BY `events`.`created_at`) AS t1
  GROUP BY t1.`area_id`, t1.`task_id`";
)
```

Comment: Thanks, that doesn't seem to work for the MySQL I'm using: ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Operand should contain 1 column(s): SELECT DISTINCT(area_id, task_id), id FROM `events`

Comment: You could use `CONCAT` to turn both columns into one and will work fine. I updated my answer to consider that and also added another solution using `.group` (which i like better).

Comment: I tried the `.group`alternative, but it picked up the oldest Event and I can't seem to order before group.

Comment: You're right, you can't order before grouping in SQL, you will need nested queries (`ORDER BY` and then `GROUP BY`) to accomplish that. I'll post new update with a nested query solution using `find_by_sql`.

Answer (score 0):

In another words you need to group events by `area_id` and `task_id`, and select recent record in each group. There [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group) about building sql-query for this case. PostgreSQL version for your table will be like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (area_id, task_id) events.*
FROM events
ORDER BY area_id ASC, task_id ASC, created_at DESC
```

And Rails code for this query:

```
Event.
  select("DISTINCT ON (area_id, task_id) events.*").
  order("area_id ASC, task_id ASC, created_at DESC")
```